# Concept of _sum in prometheus histogram

Tags: prometheus, histogram

I am so confused about `_sum` part of histogram metric.

Please explain me how to read and understand following metrics (all unrelated labels are same and omitted for briefness):

`prometheus_http_response_size_bytes_bucket`

```
prometheus_http_response_size_bytes_bucket{le="+Inf"}   1
prometheus_http_response_size_bytes_bucket{le="100"}    1
prometheus_http_response_size_bytes_bucket{le="1000"}   1
prometheus_http_response_size_bytes_bucket{le="10000"}  1
prometheus_http_response_size_bytes_bucket{le="100000"} 1
prometheus_http_response_size_bytes_bucket{le="1e+06"}  1
prometheus_http_response_size_bytes_bucket{le="1e+07"}  1
prometheus_http_response_size_bytes_bucket{le="1e+08"}  1
prometheus_http_response_size_bytes_bucket{le="1e+09"}  1
```

`prometheus_http_response_size_bytes_sum`

```
prometheus_http_response_size_bytes_sum 29
```

Shouldn't `prometheus_resposnse_size_bytes_sum`, be the sum of `prometheus_reponse_size_bytes_bucket`? If it is yes, as you see there are only nine with the result of 1. So what about value 29?